# Improve SQL performance with sub-query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables with the following structures:

transactions

| id | transaction_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 | 50 |
| 2 | 2022-04-01 | 25 |

tags

| transaction_id | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sku | SKU1 |
| 1 | account | Revenue |

I then have the following query:

```sql
SELECT
    transaction_date,
    SUM(amount),
    account,
    sku
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            transaction_date,
            amount,
            MAX(CASE WHEN tags.name = 'account' THEN tags.value END) AS account,
            MAX(CASE WHEN tags.name = 'sku' THEN tags.value END) AS sku
        FROM 
            transactions 
        LEFT JOIN
            tags on transactions.id = tags.transaction_id
            AND tags.name IN ('account', 'sku') 
        GROUP BY 
            id
    )
GROUP BY
    transaction_date,
    account,
    sku;
```

SQLite: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0554a9/1/0
Postgres: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4a7d8/5/0

My question is: how can I avoid the table scan on the outer query? The `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` output is:

```
|--CO-ROUTINE SUBQUERY 1
|  |--SCAN transactions USING INDEX idx_tid
|  `--SEARCH tags USING INDEX idx_txn_id (transaction_id=?)
|--SCAN SUBQUERY 1
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

When I fill my DB with thousands of transactions, this query is slow. I'd be interested to learn how to speed this up.

I think this problem could be reduced to the difference between these two queries:

Fast:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions

QUERY PLAN
`--SCAN transactions
```

Slow:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE id IN (SELECT transaction_id FROM tags)

QUERY PLAN
|--SEARCH transactions USING INDEX idx_tid (id=?)
`--LIST SUBQUERY 1
   `--SCAN tags USING COVERING INDEX idx_txn_id
```

How can I improve the performance of my outer query against the results of the subquery?

Comment: You're grouping the results of functions. The server can't begin to group the results before calculating the function results. It can't use any indexes either, because the indexes were created using the stored values, not the function results.

Comment: Provided `tags(transaction_id,name)` is unique you can try two joins instead of aggregation eliminating the inner query.

Comment: @Serg You are correct that `tags(transaction_id,name)` is unique. Would you mind elaborating on what the two joins would be?

Answer (score 1):

Provided `tags(transaction_id,name)` is unique, try if 2 joins will perform better

```
select
   transaction_date,
   sum(amount),
   t1.value as account,
   t2.value as sku
from 
    transactions 
left join
    tags t1 on transactions.id = t1.transaction_id and t1.name ='account'
left join
    tags t2 on transactions.id = t2.transaction_id and t2.name = 'sku'
group by
    transaction_date,
        t1.value,
    t2.value;
```

Comment: This does give some improvement - it shaves ~2s frm a query when transactions has 3M rows and tags as 8M rows.

Here is the plan:

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN transactions
|--SEARCH t1 USING INDEX unique_txn_name (transaction_id=? AND name=?)
|--SEARCH t2 USING INDEX unique_txn_name (transaction_id=? AND name=?)
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```